# Selecting words at random from given array to form sentence

Tags: java, string

I'm a beginner in java programming and was going through Ex. 16.5(Random Sentences) of Deitel&Deitel and the problem asks to form sentences with words that are randomly selected from the given array of article, noun, verb and preposition to form 20 sentences where the sentence must be formed in the order: article, noun, verb, prep, article and noun.
It asks to put spaces between the words and I do not know how to do it. Also, I've concatenated strings in a very wrong way so help and guidance would be much appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Makeit{
  private static String[] article ={"the","a","one","some","any"};
  private static String[] noun={" boy"," girl"," dog"," town"," car"};
  private static String[] verb={" drove"," jmped"," ran"," walked","    skipped"};
  private static String[] preposition={" to"," from"," over"," under"," on"};


  public static void main(String args[]){
  //order to make a sent: a,n,v,p,a,n

    System.out.println("the sentences picked at random are:");
    //loop to generate 20 sentences
    for(int i=0;i<=19;i++){
      System.out.println(makeSentence());   
    }   
  }

  public static String makeSentence(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int[] index = new int[6];
    String sent = new String();

    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
         index[i]= rand.nextInt(5);
    }
    sent = sent.concat(article[index[0]].concat(noun[index[1]].concat(verb[index[2]].concat(preposition[index[3]].concat(article[index[4]].concat(noun[index[5]]))))));
    return sent;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did they talk about `StringBuilder` at this point already?

Comment: @user1803551 using an explicit string builder is not necessary here. Multiple concatenations using `+` are compiled to use a StringBuilder internally, but it is just syntactic clutter to use it explicitly.

Comment: yes they did but i wasn't quite yet confident with the class so refrained from using it...thanks

Comment: @AndyTurner It's a pedagogical exercise. If they learned about `StringBuilder` then this is an excellent place to use it. If the sentences were longer (say it's not sentences, but a long sequence of numbers) and you were required more than 20 of them then it would be necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pick words from the arrays and store them in variables:

```
String article1 = articles[rand.nextInt(articles.length)];
String noun = nouns[rand.nextInt(nouns.length)];
// ...
```

Storing these variables directly is better than storing the indexes in an array and then retrieving the element because it is more meaningful: e.g. `index[1]` is not self-evidently the index of an element in the `noun` array, to be used to get the noun; a variable called `noun` obviously is the noun to be used in the sentence.

Then concatenation and adding spaces is quite simple:

```
sent = article1 + " " + noun + " " + verb + " " + prepo + " " + article2 + " " + noun2;
```

Note that there is no need to assign `sent = new String()`: just leave it uninitialized, or remove it entirely and return the concatenated string directly:

```
return article1 + " " + ...;
```

Comment: thanks Andy, your approach made more sense to me. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can just continue using `concat`, but on the string `" "` between every word:

```
sent.concat(article[index[0]].concat(" ").concat(noun[index[1]].concat(" ").concat(verb[index[2]])));
```

It just becomes cumbersome. Secondly, you can use the `+` operator instead of `concat` when it comes to `String`s:

```
sent = article[index[0]] + " " + noun[index[1]] + " " + verb[index[2]] + " " 
       + preposition[index[3]] + " " + article[index[4]] + " " + noun[index[5]];
```

Also, you don't need to create a new `Random` each time with `Random rand = new Random()` inside the loop. You can move it to a field or a local variable outside the loop and pass it to your sentence-making method.

Lastly, when generating the random with `nextInt(5)` you probably want to call `nextInt(noun.length)` (or another array) in case you change their size in the next "version".

Comment: i don't understand how to insert the spaces using 'concat' method....could you elaborate?

Comment: @prameshshakya Sure, I edited the answer. Do you want to see `StringBuilder` in action too? Do you understand why it's better to use it than what we are doing now?

Comment: oh i get it now..thanks...and yes the first approach to my mind was StringBuilder as it provides the mutability option and for most "editing and modification" of Strings it's recommended in addition to StringBuffer, although i wouldn't want to bother you without studying it myself first. Much thanks!

Comment: @prameshshakya Good. A tip on using this site: wait until a few answers come in instead of accepting the first one that pops - It is usually less detailed and once you accept an answer you probably won't get any more answers. You can also upvote answers which were helpful/useful regardless of which you accept.